# Matlab: 2d-array, rows different lengths

Tags: matlab, jagged-arrays

In Matlab, I want to create a two-dimensional array. However, I cannot create a matrix, because the rows are all different lengths.

I am new to Matlab, and I would normally do this in C++ by creating an array of pointers, with each pointer pointing towards its own array.

How should I do this in Matlab? Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [**cell arrays**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), which can contain data of varying types and sizes.

Like this:

```
data = {[1]; [2,2]; [3,3,3]};
```

Check out [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-cell-array.html) for more examples.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html):

```
C = {[1,2,3];
     [1,2,3,4,5];
     [1,2]};
```

Or pad with `NaN` or 0 or `Inf` etc

```
N = [1, 2, 3,   NaN, NaN;
     1, 2, 3,   4,   5;
     1, 2, NaN, NaN, NaN]
```

It really depends on what you will be doing with your data next

Answer (score 4):

Use cell ararys as mentioned by others. Listing out some code and comments to explain it -

```
%%// Create a cell array to store data
Arr = {[1 3 4 6 8]; 
       [1 8 3]; 
       [4 6 3 2];
       [6 3 6 2 6 8]}

%%// Access element (3,4)
element = Arr{3}(4)
```

Outputs

```
Arr = 

    [1x5 double]
    [1x3 double]
    [1x4 double]
    [1x6 double]


element =

     2
```

Comment: You don't need the `cell2mat` if you're popping out a single row. You can just address it with `Arr{row_id}` or `Arr{row_id}(col_id)`.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking there must be some way to directly index it!