# Matlab finding consecutive values in a vector and writing to another matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a vector with lots of consecutive values, I want to write these values in to a matrix (to do something row-wise later) but I can't quite see how to do this. For example:

```
x = [1,2,4,5,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15]
```

needs to become

```
y = [1,2;4,5;7,8,9;11,12,13,14,15]
```

I've seen a few similar posts that just check if the values are consecutive, but I can't see how to go from those posts to writing the matrix I want.

Edit: This is actually impossible as matrices need to be the same dimensions, (like I can't randomly have some rows longer than others) but I still can't see how to divide the vector up in to smaller sections of consecutive numbers.

Comment: There are many options of doing it (like a struct or if this pattern continues a lower triangular matrix), it depends also on what you are planing to do later with it.

Comment: The array `y` you want to create in not valid in MatLab; Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent

Comment: What you're looking for is often called a "ragged" or "jagged" array. Matlab's default arrays (matrices) don't support this. But you may still be able to accomplish what you need with cell arrays (see [this question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460845/matlab-2d-array-rows-different-lengths)) or by padding unused rows/columns with a value like `NaN`, or via `sparse` arrays.

Comment: @il_raffa I know I said that in the question?

Comment: @Irreducible sounds grand, can you suggest a few of the options? I want to do some more maths with the output, ideally take the RMS of the consecutive values.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) by using [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to apply an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) to groups of inputs defined by the condition that the consecutive increments within each group are `1`. Note that this works [because](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17775147/2586922) the group labels are sorted. See also [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) and [`cumsum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) to understand what the code is doing.

```
x = [1,2,4,5,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15];
ind = cumsum([true; diff(x(:))~=1]); % generate group labels
y = accumarray(ind, x(:), [], @(x){x.'}) % collect values based on group labels
```

In the example, the code gives

```
>> celldisp(y)
y{1} =
     1     2
y{2} =
     4     5
y{3} =
     7     8     9
y{4} =
    11    12    13    14    15
```

Comment: Looking good but I always get muddled up with cell arrays - once I've split it up like this, is there a way of calculating the RMS of the values? Like for i = 1:length(y) z = rms(y(i)) end

Comment: The simplest way is `cellfun(@rms, y)`. Or, using your approach: `for i = 1:length(y), z = rms(y{i}), end`